# Most frequent column value in a database table vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, tableadapter

i have a database table called parts

```
ID|Name|quanity
1 |p1   |20
2 |p2   |60
3 |p3   |200
4 |p1   |50
5 |p1   |40
6 |p3   |70
```

i want to retrieve the most frequent part name and in our example its p1 because it occurred 3 times and then i want to retrieve the name of part which has largest sum of quantity which is p3 with quantity of  270

i tried this query in my tableadapter

```
SELECT  [Name] FROM [Spareparts] GROUP BY  [Name]   ORDER BY [Name]  DESC
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: Please tag with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well . . . you need to order by the frequency, not the name:

```
SELECT [Name]
FROM [Spareparts]
GROUP BY  [Name]  
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

If you want only one row, then add `TOP (1)` or `FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY` or `LIMIT 1`, depending on your database.

EDIT:

Does this work if you include the count in the `SELECT`?

```
SELECT [Name], COUNT(*) as cnt
FROM [Spareparts]
GROUP BY  [Name]  
ORDER BY cnt DESC
```

Comment: thanks but i tried that  and it says expressions in order by list can not contain aggregate functions ;)

Comment: it works  and result gives me p1  but for the second part where i want to retrieve largest quantity